# POST values not received by server - play framework and extjs

Tags: extjs4, playframework-2.0

I am building a webservice with playframework 2 and extjs4. Until today I have managed to overcome any obstacle. But this is something I can't deal with alone. I followed [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaForms), but it didn't help me. Well, at first it did. I know it worked, I was able to add some values to the database (mongodb). I doubt if it is important, but:

- everything worked fine, I added some test data into db
- I wrote some other methods in Java
- I used `db.Category.remove()` on my mongo collection
- server is unable to receive any values from form now

I have a `Ext.FormPanel` with 2 fields:

```
items: [
    { 
        id: 'categoryName',
        fieldLabel: 'Category name', 
        name: 'categoryName', 
        allowBlank: false 
    },{
        xtype: 'textarea',
        id: 'categoryDescription',
        fieldLabel: 'Description',
        name: 'categoryDescription',
        allowBlank: true
    }
]
```

Corresponding `Model` class looks like that:

```
@MongoCollection(name = "Category")
public class CategoryModel{
    private String categoryName;
    private String categoryDescription;

    @JsonProperty("categoryName")
    public String getName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    @JsonProperty("categoryName")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.categoryName = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("categoryDescription")
    public String getDescription() {
        return categoryDescription;
    }

    @JsonProperty("categoryDescription")
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.categoryDescription = description;
    }

    public String toString(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = null;
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

And finally, here's where I want to receive values:

```
Form<CategoryModel> categoryForm = form(CategoryModel.class);
System.out.println(categoryForm);
```

Output from Play console:

`Form(of=class kunto.models.CategoryModel, data={}, value=None, errors={})`

Firebug shows that POST values are being sent correctly:

```
categoryDescription test
categoryName    test
```

And I have `POST` request type in conf/routes defined on the server side for this particular request.

I have 2 questions:

- what to do to fix it?
- more importantly, why did it happen?

**EDIT**
As @adis suggested:

```
Form<CategoryModel> categoryForm = form(CategoryModel.class).bindFromRequest();
System.out.println(categoryForm);
System.out.println(categoryForm.data());
```

outputs:

```
Form(of=class kunto.models.CategoryModel, data={categoryName=test, categoryDescription=test}, value=Some({"categoryName":null,"categoryDescription":null}), errors={})
{categoryName=test, categoryDescription=test}
```

I also checked

```
CategoryModel categoryModel = form(CategoryModel.class).bindFromRequest().get();
System.out.println(categoryModel);
```

it outputs: `{"categoryName":null,"categoryDescription":null}`

Anyone can explain this?

Comment: Can you try: Form<CategoryModel> categoryForm = form(CategoryModel.class).bindFromRequest();

Comment: @adis thanks to your comment I can see progress :D I edited my question with a small update

Comment: Could it be that you toString() method is wrong? When you print an Object java is calling always the toString() method, right? Can you delete your toString() method and instead of printing, just debug it with eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented you have to bind the request to a model by:

```
 Form<CategoryModel> categoryForm = form(CategoryModel.class).bindFromRequest();
```

This will allow you do also checks on the properties in you model if you have defined them, like: @Contraints.Required.

After the binding, you get the form object and `get` the model instance:

```
CategoryModel newCatModel = categoryForm.get();
```

This should give you an instance of your model populated with the data from your post reqeust. Usually this method looks like:

```
Form<Task> taskForm = form(Task.class).bindFromRequest();

if (taskForm.hasErrors()) {  // check for constraints
    Logger.info("Error:" + taskForm);
    return badRequest(views.html.task.create.render(taskForm));
}
// here get the model instance
Task newTask = taskForm.get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: about `@Required`: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/313. I'll give your solution a try in a few days, thanks for help!

Comment: The values are only binded if there where no validation errors. So if the email is empty, you'll get a validation error, so you'll not be able to use the `get()` method. This is not a bug, it is just the way it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this doesn't solve my problem - effect is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but the problem is gone, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but shouldn't you annotate the properties instead of the getters?

```
@JsonProperty("description")
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.categoryDescription = description;
}
```

should be

```
@JsonProperty("description")
private String description;
```

You also have a discrepancy in your code above.. the getter for description is bound to "categoryDescription" while the setter is bound to "description"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, annotating properties instead of setters/getters didn't solve my problem. `desciption` annotation was a mistake, I saw it earlier in my code, thanks for noticing - it still wasn't the source of my problem.